# Assign constant char to character array inside structure in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constants

I want a linked list structure in my VC++ application

My structure is:-

```
struct xml_data {
    int id;
    char file_name[50];
    char url_source[50];
    struct xml_Data *next;
}xml_data1;
```

If I declare a variable like

```
struct xml_data *var;
const char* abc;
```

I want to assign a value from a const char* variable to the structure members.

I tried using

```
var->file_name=abc;
```

but it is giving an error that it cannot convert const char* to char[50]...

this may be a small problem but I am very new in using data structures....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you've used new to allocate memory for the struct.

```
var = new xml_data;
```

Use `strcpy` to copy one to the other.

```
strcpy(var->file_name,abc);
```

include `<cstring>` and make sure there's enough room in the destination.

Comment: Isn't `char[50]` always enough?

Comment: @André Caron Sure, if the filenames are short :) YMMV

Comment: @jonsca......i have declared var like 
/////  xml_data *var;........is this wrong,i need a pointer to xml_data

Comment: @abhinav No, you've declared it properly.  If you want to, you can combine both on the same line as `xml_data * var = new xml_data;`

Comment: @jonsca....Thnx alot i am just declaring it xml_data* var and not using new that was the error i was making,you helped me...:)

Answer (score 1):

`xml_data::file_name` is an array and is **not modifiable**. It always sticked to the `&file_name[0]` (address of 1st element).

At the max you can copy the content of the pointer into that array using `strcpy`/`strncpy`/`memcpy` or equivalent.